# IUPAC nomenclature: putting the number before or in the middle of the name

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Which is preferred according to "strict" IUPAC:

2-pentanone or pentan-2-one ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name “2-pentanone” and “pentan-2-one” describe the same compound. The name “2-pentanone” is in accordance with obsolete IUPAC Recommendations. The relevant rule of the IUPAC Nomenclature was changed in the 1993 IUPAC Recommendations:

> **R-0.1.2** Position of locants
>
> Locants (numerals and/or letters) are placed immediately before the part of the name to which they relate, except in the case of traditional contracted forms (see R-2.5).

The current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.3.2** Position of locants
>
> Locants (numerals and/or letters) are placed immediately before that part of the name to which they relate, except in the case of the traditional contracted names when locants are placed at the front of their names.

Examples:

- hex-2-ene (not 2-hexene)
- cyclohex-2-en-1-ol (not 2-cyclohexen-1-ol)
- pentan-2-one (not 2-pentanone)
- (propan-2-yl)benzene

Examples for traditional contracted names with locants at the front of the name:

- 2-naphthyl (not naphth-2-yl), the preferred name is naphthalen-2-yl
- 2-pyridyl (not pyrid-2-yl), the preferred name is pyridin-2-yl

Comment: so in that case would the IUPAC names for MIBK and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Vinylpyrrolidone

be 4-Methyl-2-pentanone

and

N-ethenyl pyrrolid-2-one respectively ?   Whenever I lookup IUPAC names online they seem to be pretty all over the place with this convention :/

Comment: @Some_Guy The preferred IUPAC names are “4-methylpentan-2-one” and “1-ethenylpyrrolidin-2-one”. The locants “2-” are placed immediately before the suffix “-one” to which they relate.

Comment: Thanks.  While we're here, why is N-*R*yl not correct?

Comment: @Some_Guy The locant “_N_-” is not necessarily wrong; for pyrrolidin, however, the locant “1-” is preferred. Anyway, if you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @Some_Guy Comments are not meant for follow-up questions. If you have a new question, ask it. If it's too trivial to be a question, maybe it's not a question that would require a lot of thinking or research.